# FilterSpec not available in Django1.4

Tags: django, reporting-services

Can someone pls help me out. I am working on a django app and I need to do some reporting. But I want to create an admin back end for the reporting where administrators can see the models and like filter and stuff. I dnt want to use django admin, I want another interface sort of. I want to reserve the dajango admin for myself as a developer and create another interface for other administrators. Can u recommend any good apps I can check out pls. Is there a django reporting app that supports version >=1.4. 1.4 does not have filterspecs so its hard for me to find the right app. I am using geraldo but it seems its for pdf reports only.

Answer (score 0):

I use Geraldo Reports before but I did not pursue it because you will be dismay. It is really good but it's not maintained. So I search for another app but I did not see anything. In the last, I created my own reports. Why not create other admin on your own instead.